# How to remove Duplicate record from a custom array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to remove duplicate records from my custom generated array using php. But i am getting same array.Below is the input array and needed array after filtering.

INPUT ARRAY:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CSG] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 1111
                    [group_name] => GRP NAME 1
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [TFE] => Array
                (
                    [track_fb_export_id] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CSG] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 2222
                    [group_name] => GRP NAME 2
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [TFE] => Array
                (
                    [track_fb_export_id] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CSG] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 2222
                    [group_name] => GRP NAME 2
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [TFE] => Array
                (
                    [track_fb_export_id] => 
                )

        )

)
```

WHAT IS EXPECTED RESULT:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [CSG] => Array
                    (
                        [group_id] => 1111
                        [group_name] => GRP NAME 1
                        [status] => 1
                    )

                [TFE] => Array
                    (
                        [track_fb_export_id] => 
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [CSG] => Array
                    (
                        [group_id] => 2222
                        [group_name] => GRP NAME 2
                        [status] => 1
                    )

                [TFE] => Array
                    (
                        [track_fb_export_id] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

THE GRP NAME 2 with group_id is duplicate so want to remove duplicate groups from array.

CODE I TRIED:

```
$unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
//data array
$data = array();

//group id collector
$group_id = array();

//the index won't change now 
foreach($input as $key=>$value)
{
    if(!in_array($value['CSG']['group_id'], $group_id))
    {
        $group_id[] = $value['CSG']['group_id'];
        $data[] = $value;
    }

}

//check the data
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Be careful this is a **O(n²)** algorithm.

Comment: My answer give you a **O(n*log(n))** algorithm, take a look.

Comment: until you are checking the [TFE] => Array([track_fb_export_id] =>) this will be best

Comment: I am just checking "group_id or group_name" for duplicate entry... no tracking information is checked for duplicate entry..

Comment: This is the simplest way if you sort also you need to process in this same manner. there is no option i got

Answer (score 0):

A few steps:

- First, you have to sort your array regarding the `group_name`:

```php
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $sa = $a['CSG']['group_name'];
    $sb = $b['CSG']['group_name'];
    $compare = strcmp($a, $b);

    if($compare > 0)
        return 1;
    else if($compare < 0) 
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

The function [uasort](http://php.net/uasort) takes an array and a function which will be called to sort the array.

- Then travel your array and make an other array. You can keep the last entry you add in your new array, and compare it with the current entry, thanks to the sorting you did previously.

```php
$newArray = array();
$lastArray = null;

foreach($a as $array) {
    if($lastArray == null || $a['CSG']['group_name'] != $lastArray['CSG']['group_name']) {
        $lastArray = $a;
        $newArray[] = $a;
    }
}
```